# Add attribute to product

Tags: php, magento

Hello Stackoverflowers

I have been given the assignment of expanding the Magento API with a new product attribute: finalPrice.

The method of finding the finalprice i got pinned down, but adding the attribute is kind of a mystery to me. In the past i have been trying to do something similar, by using an install script, but never got it to work.

What is the correct approach to this ?

Comment: in which api method you want to add this attribute?

Comment: I am not sure. Let's just say i want to be able to get it via. a product object. Is that product-info?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you want to import or export new product EAV attribute by the Magento API.

Then go to Magento admin panel, Catalog/Attributes/ create new attribute.

In the api you can call that attribute value by for example:

```
$product->getSku();
// or
$product->getName();
```

Rules for calling are:
If your attribute ID is Something_like-this or finalPrice, You will call:

```
$product->getSomethingLikeThis();
// or
$product->getFinalprice();
```

And you will get the value.

Comment: This could work. Is it possible to define the content the new attribute, programmatically ? Finalprice should be the price, after price rules and discounts are calculated. I already created the function, and placed it in a helper module

Comment: I mean, i want to give the attribute value, automatically. Final price should be the price after all price rules and discounts are applied. Therefore it should be dynamic, done via the code?

Comment: This is not a task for API, but for some controller on Magento side, before you get the value. Or you can call all needed values, count it manually and save by function setFinalprice back to Magento.

Comment: Im not quite sure i understand your last comment. I should create the field in the admin panel, and what do i then do to dynamically fill in the values?

Comment: You can use 2 ways:
1 is to create a controller based module thad did the filling of values for you
2 is to create a script for export each product in loop, get a values needed to count your prices, math count your Finalprice and save back again. Maybye better is use standard programatical way, not needed use API.

Comment: Thanks for the anwers. I will get back when i have tried it :)